# Webcam driversfor HP Laptop G6000

Tags: webcam, ubuntu-drivers

I have successfully installed Ubuntu on an old HP G6000 which used to have Windows Vista, and I thought had given up the ghost. Now it is amazing; I am delighted.

The bit that doesn't work is the webcam in the lid of the laptop; can anyone give me a clue on how to find a driver and install it for that Webcam?

Comment: Please run `sudo lsusb` then copy the results, click [edit], and add the results to your question.